# Ajax and JS on select_taf; SyntaxError: missing } after property list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

what is wrong with my Js and AJAX code? I am using ajax and JS on select_tag and I am getting errors with ajax;

```
- @departments = @collocation_request.collocation_request_departments

 td Reviewer
      - @departments.each do |department|
           td
              div.input-append
                = select_tag :reviewer_id, options_from_collection_for_select(User.where(department_id:                   department.department_id), "id","full_name"), prompt: 'Select a Reviewer', remote: true

    javascript:
          $(function(){
            $(document).on('change','#reviewer_id',function(e) {
                alert($(this).val());
                var collocation_request_id = $(this).data('collocation-request-id');
                var departments_id = $(this).data('department-id');
                jQuery.ajax({
                  type: "PUT",
                  dataType: 'JSON',
                  data: {collocation_request_department: {reviewer: $(this).val()},
                  url: '/collocation_requests/'+collocation_request_id+'/departments/'+departments_id+'.js'
                }).complete(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                window.location = window.location;
                });
              });
          });
```

Comment: You're getting an error that says "missing }" because your code is missing a "}" on the "data:" line in the ajax argument. What isn't clear about that?

Comment: I added the missing part. JS is working but PUT function isn't. not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `}` in the data

```
data: {collocation_request_department: {reviewer: $(this).val()}},
```

Comment: Anik: the JS and AJAX are working, however the PUT function does not, here is other part of code: